# Json object and Spring controller the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (bad request)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to share the following experience which took me around two days to fix it: 
Tools: Spring MVC 3.2.3, Roo 1.2.4, Java 7.

I tried to pass a Json object to my controller as follow:

.js file

```
    var params= { 
        "eItemId" : p1,
        "eItemCode" : p2, 
        "eItemPartNbr" : p3, 
        "eItemDesc" : p4,
        "uomItemSlctId" : p5,
        "eForAnyCompany" : flag 
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/item/saveitem",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    cache: false,.....
```

I adapted the controller method signature a lot without success, and finally I keep it simple as from the beginning:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveitem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> saveItem(@RequestBody ItemFormBean itemToEdit) {..}
```

The frequently error message was:

*the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (bad request): Bad Request 400*

To figure it out what happened I had to low the log level to realize  the problem and I found:

> DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.Map com.jarbits.quo.web.ItemController.saveItem(com.company.ItemFormBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "eItemId" (class com.company.ItemFormBean), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "eitemId", "eitemPartNbr", "eitemCode", "eforAnyCompany", "eitemDesc", "uomItemSlctId"])

The bean that map the Json object is:

```
@RooJavaBean
public class ItemFormBean {
    @NotNull
    private Long eItemId;
    @Size(min=3, max=30) 
    private String eItemCode;
    @Size(min=3, max=30)
    private String eItemPartNbr;
    @NotNull
    private String eItemDesc;
    @NotNull
    private Long uomItemSlctId;
    private boolean eForAnyCompany;
}
```

Next the result..

---

Here the results..
So, the Json object description is correct based on bean definition, however the controller was expecting to receive:

> "eitemId", "eitemPartNbr", "eitemCode", "eforAnyCompany", "eitemDesc", "uomItemSlctId"

instead of:

> "eItemId", "eItemPartNbr", "eItemCode", "eForAnyCompany", "eItemDesc", "uomItemSlctId"

Also, I'd like to mention that I have the following setting at webmvc-config.xml file.

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="false" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
    <property name="mediaTypes" >
        <value>
            atom=application/atom+xml
            html=text/html
            json=application/json
            *=*/*
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This because ***@ResponseBody*** was not returning json objects results.

@ Emrakul,  @Humdinger I did the test with a downgrade of Jackson 2.0  as follow:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core
jackson-annotations 2.4.1 to 2.3.3
jackson-core 2.4.1.1 to 2.3.4
jackson-databind 2.4.1.3 to 2.3.4
```

I got exactly the same defect.

As you said  folks this is a defect with Jackson framework. Could you please share your thoughts ?

I hope this defect can help to others.

Comment: This is good, but there are a couple things you could do to improve it. When self-answering questions, please actually post an answer to your question with the information in it. Then, make sure your question stands alone and looks good on its own. In this way, somebody who does not know you self-answered the question would think both the question and answer are good. Thanks for spreading your knowledge!

Comment: Looks to me like this IS in fact a defect. Have you tried changing the json to the lower case "bad" versions just to see what happens?

Comment: Thank you Emraku, I'll do it the next time. Humdinger, I'll try, and I'll keep you posted. Thanks folks.

Comment: Do you have getters and setters?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce your problem was with

```
public class ItemFormBean {
    private String eItemCode;
    public String getEItemCode() {
        return eItemCode;
    }
    public void setEItemCode(String eItemCode) {
        this.eItemCode = eItemCode;
    }
}
```

with

```
{ ..., "eItemCode" : "asd", ... }
```

which yields

```
Unrecognized field "eItemCode" (ItemFormBean) (6 known properties: ..., "eitemCode", ...])
```

Jackson, by default, uses your getters to determine property names. It does this by getting rid of the `get` or `is` prefix and lowercasing any leading capital characters.

So `getEItemCode` will turn into `eitemCode`. And that's what it will expect from the JSON.

If you want, you can set it explicitly by annotating one of the getter, setter, or field with `@JsonProperty("eItemCode")`.

Comment: Thanks *@Sotirios Delimanolis*, that's right, however the defect is something uncommon, the common sense says what is expecting is just to have the first capital after "get"... I meant, getXzzzz where zzz can be capital or minuscule, and Json should follow the same sense.

Right, the setters and getter are in .aj files, this because Roo (@RooJavaBean) framework maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *@Sotirios Delimanolis*, that's right, however the defect is something uncommon, the common sense says what is expecting is just to have the first capital after "get"... I meant, getXzzzz where zzz can be capital or minuscule, and Json should follow the same sense.

Right, the setters and getter are in .aj files, this because Roo (@RooJavaBean) framework maintenance.